# Azure Functions HTTP trigger python text to speech program

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions, text-to-speech, serverless

I have developed a Text to Speech python program and the program will saved as MP3 file

```
from gtts import gTTS 
  
# import Os module to start the audio file
import os 

fh = open("test.txt", "r",encoding='UTF-8')
myText = fh.read().replace("\n", " ")

# Language we want to use 
language = 'en'

output = gTTS(text=myText, lang=language, slow=False)

output.save("output.mp3")
fh.close()

# Play the converted file 
os.system("start output.mp3")
```

Now I want to trigger this program by using Azure Functions HTTP trigger python program
But I don't know how to edit the *init*.py in VScode

```
import logging
# Import the Gtts module for text  
# to speech conversion 
from gtts import gTTS 
import azure.functions as func
# import Os module to start the audio file
import os 
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

My question is how to do a local test by postman to merge my python code in *int*.py and successfully trigger the program to output a mp3 file?

Many thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just need to put your code under the

`logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')`

will be ok.

I think the code can be like this:

```
import logging
# Import the Gtts module for text  
# to speech conversion 
from gtts import gTTS 
import azure.functions as func
# import Os module to start the audio file
import os 
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    #Put your logic here.
    return func.HttpResponse(f"test.")
```

Comment: i just copy my python code into #Put your logic here. , but it is not working, the environment doesn't recognize the variable fh , would you mind explain more?

Comment: Why not? could you please share your code?

Comment: please see the attached photo above